# Algorithm for reducing texture changes in collection of meshes

Tags: algorithm, sorting, graphics, path-finding

I have a collection of meshes, where each mesh can have 1 to N number of textures. I am searching for an algorithm which would allow me to sort the meshes to reduce the number of texture changes. It's relatively trivial to group together meshes which use a single texture, what I am finding tricky is:

1. In the case where a mesh uses two textures (which I'll denote as texture A and B), sorting the collection so that the group of meshes that only use texture A are all drawn first, then the meshes that load A and B, and then the meshes that only use B.
2. In the case where a mesh uses N textures (For example 3, which I'll denote as texture A, B and C), figuring out the best way to organize the faces in that mesh so that the trivial groups can be loaded in a manner similar to 1). As an example, I could reorganize the mesh's faces so that the loading order is [B A C], or [C B A]. This effectively lets me ignore the texture loads in the middle and I can treat it as a mesh with two textures (which would be [B C] and [C A] respectively).

A different way to describe this problem would be: I have a collection of "tasks" to do. Each task requires me to visit from 1 to N **unique** nodes in a collection of nodes. I can have multiples of the same task, but each time I redo a task I must travel nodes in the same order as last time. Find the path that reduces the number of state changes (where a state change is moving from one node to a different node).

I assume there's already an algorithm for something similar to what I'm trying to accomplish, possibly some sort of path finding algorithm, or potentially something that is already implemented in modern graphics libraries/drivers.

Please do not tell me that "it would be more efficient to sort your meshes by their Z instead" or to split my meshes by textures, it is not the point of this question. This is not for a real-time application.

Comment: Is a state change from using textures [A B] to using textures [C D] more expensive than a state change to using [A D].  In other words, is it the primary cost that just a state change (of any kind) has been made? (e.g. I could imaging that telling the driver to change which textures are bound to which units is a constant time operation regardless of how many texture units are updated.)  In this case it may be best to take advantage of the max texture units that can be loaded simultaneously. and just access 0,0 uvs for unused textures relying on cache performance. I don't actually know.

Comment: Would sorting lexicography meet your requirements ? For example sorting `a,ab,ac,abc,b, bc,c` into `a, ab, abc, ac, b, bc, c` ? Another approach is to assign a cost to any exchange and use BFS to minimize exchanges (uniform cost search).

Comment: @Wyck In this particular case, this is for an old game console (Nintendo64 specifically), so I do not have access to fancy modern day solutions. The N64 has an incredibly small 4kb texture cache, meaning that to take advantage of loading multiple textures would require incredibly small texture sizes.

Comment: @c0der Yes lexicographical sorting would be one way to tackle this problem.

Comment: lexicographical sorting is quite straightforward: https://www.online-ide.com/7gqNtwXu5G

Answer (score 1):

When I was writing this question I had an inkling that the problem was in some way related to the [Traveling Salesman Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem), but I wasn't 100% sure so I removed the tags just to be safe. After thinking about the question further, however, I did reach the conclusion that my hunch was right.

My approach to solving the problem is as follows:

I start with a collection of models (which I have defined here as "Segments"):

[image: Step 1]

I duplicate for all possible variations of texture loads. For instance, a segment that loads 3 textures has 3 factorial variations to how it can load textures:

[image: Step 2]

Next, I group segments by texture loads:

[image: Step 3]

Now I generate a network connecting all groups to each other, where a texture load (between groups) incurs a cost of 1 and no texture loads is 0. There is no need to connect groups which share segments as that is redundant (in this example, no need to connect A+B and B+A):

[image: Step 4]

This is a TSP, so now just solve for the shortest path using your preferred method. here is a possible solution (Note that B+A is ignored since A+B already loads those two segments):

[image: Step 5]

Here's the output from running this algorithm on [this model](https://github.com/buu342/Blender-Sausage64/blob/master/Sample%20Model/Catherine.blend) using a nearest neighbor solution. Might not be the best solution (although it seems correct) but it is definitely a better approach than brute-forcing all 28 factorial possible solutions:

[image: Answer]